Is there way to store/log the gramex's lineprofile decorator's output in app's gramex.log file?
I am currently using gramex lineprofile​ decorator for API profiling and it is working well, as I can see the output printed successfully in the Gramex console on my local setup.
I would like to know if there is a way to store or log this lineprofile output in the application's gramex.log file, where we store all other application logs. This would help me trace the detailed performance of my API on the server, including performance metrics post-cached.
Could you please assist me with this how can I achieve it ?
Note- currently I am using gramex=1.80.0
